# Get browser version using Selenium WebDriver and Ruby

Tags: ruby, selenium-webdriver, webdriver, firefox-marionette, geckodriver

Trying to extract the browser version without making a system call. Below is my Ruby code.

```
#!/usr/bin/env ruby

require "selenium-webdriver"

# Tell the Ruby bindings to use Marionette.
# This will not be necessary in the future,
# when Selenium will default to marionette

caps = Selenium::WebDriver::Remote::Capabilities.firefox marionette: true
browser = Selenium::WebDriver.for :firefox, :desired_capabilities => caps

puts browser.capabilities["version"]
```

There is nothing returned to the terminal after execution.

Answer (score 0):

I tested this with selenium. It seems this line is the problem:

```
puts browser.capabilities["version"]
```

Here's two ways to get at the version:

```
browser.capabilities.version
browser.capabilities.send(:capabilities)[:version]
```

Answer (score 0):

With selenium-webdriver (3.4.0)

```
browser_version = case @driver.browser
                  when :firefox
                    @driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent;').split('/')[-1]
                  when :chrome, :safari
                    @driver.capabilities[:version]
                  when :ie
                    @driver.execute_script('return navigator.userAgent;').split("MSIE ")[1].split(";")[0]
                  end
```